# Xcode Debug View Hierarchy finding viewcontroller

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

Does the  Debug View Hierarchy in Xcode allow me to see what view controller owns a view?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Update:** Starting with Xcode 9, view controllers are listed right along the view hierarchy in the visual debugger.

You can get the memory address of the selected view from the inspector in Xcode and then use the console to get the view's view controller using `-nextResponder`.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/nextResponder

> UIView implements this method by returning the UIViewController object
>   that manages it (if it has one) or its superview (if it doesn’t)

Comment: An example would be `(lldb) po [0x0123456789ab nextResponder]`, right?

Comment: That should work, you may need to cast the pointer to (id) if lldb complains.

Comment: what exactly works in during view debug hierarchy? When I use it, I can see the pointer to UIlabels, but when I try to do something like `po 0x7fb1de6e2030.text` I get an error. I was hoping somehow I could cast it to UILabel but had no success there. Any solution?

Comment: This is unrelated to view controllers, but `po [(UILabel *)0x7fb1de6e2030 text]` should work.